# Как сделать анимацию иконки - разбитое сердце

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, анимация

У меня есть две иконки сердечка - целого и разбитого.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо сделать анимацию перехода иконки из одного состояния в другое.
По рисункам видно, что анимация сводится к повороту одной половинки сердца относительно другой половинки, вокруг одной общей точки.

Необходимо, чтобы анимация начиналась при клике по иконке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CSS**

Реализация следующая:

1. Рисуем два сердечка с применением свойства `border-radius`
2. Накладываем сердечки друг на друга
3. С помощью свойства `clip-path: polygon()`, указывая нужные координаты, где должна проходить линия разлома, отсекаем половинки
4. При наведении на общий контейнер, с помощью свойства `rotate` применяем анимацию вращения, и свойства `translateX` сдвигаем элементы по горизонтали в разные стороны

Анимация при наведении:

```css
body {display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; min-height: 100vh; margin: 0;}

.container {position: relative; width: 200px; height: 165px;}

.heart__one, .heart__two {
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 200px; height: 165px; transition: all 2s 1s;
}

.heart__one {
  clip-path: polygon( 0 0, 100px 0, 100px 40px, 90px 63px, 110px 80px, 90px 100px, 110px 120px, 100px 140px, 100px 100%, 0 100%);
}
.heart__two {
  clip-path: polygon( 100px 0, 100px 40px, 90px 63px, 110px 80px, 90px 100px, 110px 120px, 100px 140px, 100px 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0);
}

.heart__one::before, .heart__one::after,
.heart__two::before, .heart__two::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute; top: 4px; left: 100px; width: 100px; height: 160px;
  background: #dc143c; border-radius: 100px 100px 0 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg); transform-origin: 0 100%;
}

.heart__one::after, .heart__two::after {
  left: 0; transform: rotate(45deg); transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}

.container:hover .heart__one {
  transform: rotate(-5deg) translateX(-7px); transition: all 1s;
}
.container:hover .heart__two {
  transform: rotate(5deg) translateX(7px); transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="heart__one"></div>
  <div class="heart__two"></div>
</div>
```

Анимация по клику:

```js
let heart = document.querySelector('.container');
heart.onclick = function(){
document.querySelector('.heart__one').classList.add("heart__one__active");
document.querySelector('.heart__two').classList.add("heart__two__active");
setTimeout(function() {
document.querySelector('.heart__one').classList.remove("heart__one__active");
document.querySelector('.heart__two').classList.remove("heart__two__active");
}, 1000);
}
```

```css
body {display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; min-height: 100vh; margin: 0;}

.container {position: relative; width: 200px; height: 165px;}

.heart__one, .heart__two {
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 200px; height: 165px; transition: all 2s 1s;
}

.heart__one {
  clip-path: polygon( 0 0, 100px 0, 100px 40px, 90px 63px, 110px 80px, 90px 100px, 110px 120px, 100px 140px, 100px 100%, 0 100%);
}
.heart__two {
  clip-path: polygon( 100px 0, 100px 40px, 90px 63px, 110px 80px, 90px 100px, 110px 120px, 100px 140px, 100px 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0);
}

.heart__one::before, .heart__one::after,
.heart__two::before, .heart__two::after {
  content: ""; cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute; top: 4px; left: 100px; width: 100px; height: 160px;
  background: #dc143c; border-radius: 100px 100px 0 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg); transform-origin: 0 100%;
}

.heart__one::after, .heart__two::after {
  left: 0; transform: rotate(45deg); transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}

.heart__one__active {
  transform: rotate(-5deg) translateX(-7px); transition: all 1s;
}
.heart__two__active {
  transform: rotate(5deg) translateX(7px); transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="heart__one"></div>
  <div class="heart__two"></div>
</div>
```

Немного усложним анимацию и добавим легких эффектов:

```js
let heart = document.querySelector('.container');
heart.onclick = function(){
document.querySelector('.heart__one').classList.add("heart__one__active");
document.querySelector('.heart__two').classList.add("heart__two__active");
document.querySelector('body').classList.add("body__black");
setTimeout(function() {
document.querySelector('.heart__one').classList.remove("heart__one__active");
document.querySelector('.heart__two').classList.remove("heart__two__active");
document.querySelector('body').classList.remove("body__black");
}, 4600);
}
```

```css
body {display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; min-height: 100vh; margin: 0; background: pink;}

.container {position: relative; width: 200px; height: 165px;}

.heart__one, .heart__two {
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 200px; height: 165px;
}

.heart__one {
  clip-path: polygon( 0 0, 100px 0, 100px 40px, 90px 63px, 110px 80px, 90px 100px, 110px 120px, 100px 140px, 100px 100%, 0 100%);
}
.heart__two {
  clip-path: polygon( 100px 0, 100px 40px, 90px 63px, 110px 80px, 90px 100px, 110px 120px, 100px 140px, 100px 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0);
}

.heart__one::before, .heart__one::after,
.heart__two::before, .heart__two::after {
  content: ""; cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute; top: 4px; left: 100px; width: 100px; height: 160px;
  background: #dc143c; border-radius: 100px 100px 0 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg); transform-origin: 0 100%;
}

.heart__one::after, .heart__two::after {
  left: 0; transform: rotate(45deg); transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}

.heart__one__active {animation: ani1 2s forwards 2.5s;}
.heart__two__active {animation: ani2 2s forwards 2.5s;}

@keyframes ani1 {
  0% {transform: rotate(-8deg) translateX(-11px);}
  2% {transform: rotate(-2deg) translateX(-3px);}
  8% {transform: rotate(-7deg) translateX(-10px);}
  13% {transform: rotate(-3deg) translateX(-4px);}
  18% {transform: rotate(-6deg) translateX(-8px);}
  22% {transform: rotate(-4deg) translateX(-5px);}
  25% {transform: rotate(-5deg) translateX(-7px);}
  60% {transform: rotate(-5deg) translateX(-7px);}
  100% {transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(0);}
}
@keyframes ani2 {
  0% {transform: rotate(8deg) translateX(11px);}
  2% {transform: rotate(2deg) translateX(3px);}
  8% {transform: rotate(7deg) translateX(10px);}
  13% {transform: rotate(3deg) translateX(4px);}
  18% {transform: rotate(6deg) translateX(8px);}
  22% {transform: rotate(4deg) translateX(5px);}
  25% {transform: rotate(5deg) translateX(7px);}
  60% {transform: rotate(5deg) translateX(7px);}
  100% {transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(0);}
}

.body__black {width: 100%; animation: ani 2s forwards 0.1s;}

@keyframes ani {
  0% {background: pink;}
  100% {background: black;}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="heart__one"></div>
  <div class="heart__two"></div>
</div>
```

Получилось неплохо. Но разбитое сердце – это не всегда есть хорошо, и его действительно невозможно склеить. Поэтому, я всем желаю, чтобы у вас всегда было только так:

```css
body {display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; min-height: 100vh; margin: 0; background: pink;}

.heart {
  position: relative; width: 200px; height: 165px;
  animation: ani1 1.5s infinite 0.5s;
}

.heart::before, .heart::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute; top: 4px; left: 100px; width: 100px; height: 160px;
  background: #dc143c; border-radius: 100px 100px 0 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg); transform-origin: 0 100%;
  animation: ani2 1.5s infinite 0.5s;
}
.heart::after {
  left: 0; transform: rotate(45deg); transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}

@keyframes ani1 {
  10% {transform: scale(1.1);}
  20% {transform: scale(1);}
  30% {transform: scale(1.1);}
  40% {transform: scale(1);}
}
@keyframes ani2 {
  30% {background: red;}
  50% {background: #dc143c;}
}
```

```html
<div class="heart"></div>
```

Comment: Отличное решение CSS! Но ты же хотел SVG штудировать :)

Comment: и тебе удачи и успехов во всех делах и начинаниях.

Answer (score 13):

Для реализации анимации необходимо нарисовать линию разлома и две половинки иконки.

- Берем первую иконку и загружаем её в векторный редактор.
- С помощью инструмента - рисовать кривые Безье и прямые линии -
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

  рисуем линию разлома

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Этим же инструментом обводим контур левой половинки сердца и ещё раз
  обводим контур, но правой половинки сердца. Каждый раз делаем контур
  замкнутым.
- Сохраняем файл `Heart.svg` в векторном редакторе
- Копируем из файла патчи левой и правой половинок сердца.

*Ниже пример правой половинки*

```html
<svg id="heart" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
<style>
#right-half{
 fill:#dc143c;
}
</style> 
  <g>
    <path id="right-half"  d="M63.9 24C58.5 24 53.5 27 50.2 32.5 49.8 35.3 50.5 40.6 50.5 40.6L48.8 45.2 53.8 49.7 47.6 55.5 54 57.8 49.8 61.6C49.7 69.1 50.2 69 50.1 75.4 50.1 75.4 50.2 75.7 50.2 75.7 50.6 75.7 51 75.5 51.1 75.1 53 70.1 58 66.3 63.4 62.2 70.9 56.5 78.6 50.7 79.2 41.1 79.4 36.4 77.9 32 74.8 28.8 73.5 27.4 72 26.3 70.4 25.5 68.4 24.5 66.1 24 63.9 24z"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

*Левая половинка иконки*

```html
<svg id="heart" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
<style>
#left-half{
 fill:#dc143c;
}
</style> 
  <g >
    <path  id="left-half" d="m50.1 75.4c0 0 0.1 0.3 0.1 0.3-0.4 0-0.8-0.3-0.9-0.7-1.9-5.1-7-9-12.4-13-7.3-5.5-14.9-11.2-15.6-20.9-0.3-4.5 1.1-8.8 4.2-12 3-3.2 7.2-5.1 11.5-5.1 5.5 0 10.3 3.1 13.4 8.5-0.4 2.9 0.3 8.1 0.3 8.1l-1.7 4.6 5 4.5-6.2 5.8 6.4 2.4-4.2 3.8c0 7.4 0.4 7.4 0.3 13.7z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

- Соединяем две половинки сердца в одном файле и начинаем писать код
  анимации половинок.

### Пишем код анимации

Анимация очень простая,- вращение половинок вокруг общей точки в разные стороны.
Для вращения правой половинки по часовой стрелке используется команда:

```
<animateTransform id="break" attributeName="transform" type="rotate"
 begin="heart.click" dur="1s" repeatCount="1" values="0 50 75.7;7 50 75.7" 

fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive"/>
```

Начало анимации - `begin="heart.click"`

Вращение на `7 градусов` вокруг точки с координатами `50 75.7` - `values="0 50 75.7;7 50 75.7"`

Для левой половинки вращение будет вокруг той же точки, но против часовой стрелки. Поэтому будет отрицательное значение угла поворота:

`values="0 50 75.7;-7 50 75.7"`

*Собираем всё вместе:*

```html
<svg id="heart" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
<style>
#right-half, #left-half{
 fill:#dc143c;
}
</style> 
<title>To break heart</title>
  <g>
    <path id="right-half"  d="M63.9 24C58.5 24 53.5 27 50.2 32.5 49.8 35.3 50.5 40.6 50.5 40.6L48.8 45.2 53.8 49.7 47.6 55.5 54 57.8 49.8 61.6C49.7 69.1 50.2 69 50.1 75.4 50.1 75.4 50.2 75.7 50.2 75.7 50.6 75.7 51 75.5 51.1 75.1 53 70.1 58 66.3 63.4 62.2 70.9 56.5 78.6 50.7 79.2 41.1 79.4 36.4 77.9 32 74.8 28.8 73.5 27.4 72 26.3 70.4 25.5 68.4 24.5 66.1 24 63.9 24z">
      <animateTransform id="break" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="heart.click" dur="1s" repeatCount="1" values="0 50 75.7;7 50 75.7" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive"/>
    </path>
  </g>
  <g>
    <path  id="left-half" d="m50.1 75.4c0 0 0.1 0.3 0.1 0.3-0.4 0-0.8-0.3-0.9-0.7-1.9-5.1-7-9-12.4-13-7.3-5.5-14.9-11.2-15.6-20.9-0.3-4.5 1.1-8.8 4.2-12 3-3.2 7.2-5.1 11.5-5.1 5.5 0 10.3 3.1 13.4 8.5-0.4 2.9 0.3 8.1 0.3 8.1l-1.7 4.6 5 4.5-6.2 5.8 6.4 2.4-4.2 3.8c0 7.4 0.4 7.4 0.3 13.7z" >
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="heart.click" dur="1s" repeatCount="1" values="0 50 75.7;-7 50 75.7" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive"/>
    </path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

*Анимация начинается при клике на иконку*

**Вариант анимации с обратным склеванием половинок**

```html
<svg id="heart" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
<style>
#right-half, left-half{
 fill:#dc143c;
}
</style> 
<title>Icon to break and collect</title>
  <g>  
    <path id="right-half"  d="M63.9 24C58.5 24 53.5 27 50.2 32.5 49.8 35.3 50.5 40.6 50.5 40.6L48.8 45.2 53.8 49.7 47.6 55.5 54 57.8 49.8 61.6C49.7 69.1 50.2 69 50.1 75.4 50.1 75.4 50.2 75.7 50.2 75.7 50.6 75.7 51 75.5 51.1 75.1 53 70.1 58 66.3 63.4 62.2 70.9 56.5 78.6 50.7 79.2 41.1 79.4 36.4 77.9 32 74.8 28.8 73.5 27.4 72 26.3 70.4 25.5 68.4 24.5 66.1 24 63.9 24z">
      <animateTransform  id="break"
        attributeName="transform"
        type="rotate"
        begin="heart.click"
        dur="1s"
        repeatCount="1"
        values="0 50 75.7;7 50 75.7"
        fill="freeze"
        restart="whenNotActive"/>
      <animateTransform
        attributeName="transform"
        type="rotate"
        begin="break.end+1.5s"
        dur="1s" repeatCount="1"
        values="7 50 75.7;0 50 75.7"
        fill="freeze"
        restart="whenNotActive"/>
    </path>
  </g>
  <g>
    <path  id="right-half" d="m50.1 75.4c0 0 0.1 0.3 0.1 0.3-0.4 0-0.8-0.3-0.9-0.7-1.9-5.1-7-9-12.4-13-7.3-5.5-14.9-11.2-15.6-20.9-0.3-4.5 1.1-8.8 4.2-12 3-3.2 7.2-5.1 11.5-5.1 5.5 0 10.3 3.1 13.4 8.5-0.4 2.9 0.3 8.1 0.3 8.1l-1.7 4.6 5 4.5-6.2 5.8 6.4 2.4-4.2 3.8c0 7.4 0.4 7.4 0.3 13.7z" >
      <animateTransform
        attributeName="transform"
        type="rotate"
        begin="heart.click"
        dur="1s"
        repeatCount="1"
        values="0 50 75.7;-7 50 75.7"
        fill="freeze"
        restart="whenNotActive"/>
      <animateTransform
        attributeName="transform"
        type="rotate"
        begin="break.end+1.5s"
        dur="1s"
        repeatCount="1"
        values="-7 50 75.7;0 50 75.7"
        fill="freeze"
        restart="whenNotActive"/>
    </path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Это разбитое сердце невозможно склеить. Оно опять сразу разваливается.

Comment: @MindCleaner Сейчас будет второй вариант, где оно склеится :)

Comment: *разбитое сердце невозможно склеить* - это не баг, это реализм :]

Comment: Если присмотреться, то сердца изначально треснутые. И цвет второго сердца какой-то не тот.

Comment: @MindCleaner сделай своё - целое, с нужным цветом. Выше же написали, разбитое сердце не склеить.

Comment: @MindCleaner заменил цвет :)